# Table containing duplicates needs a mass update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table containing data like this

| transactionCode | column2 | column3 | column4 | wCode | aCode | column7 | column8 | column9 | column10 | liNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7938636 | 2 | INVOICE | NULL | 1 | MZ690577 | 2021-01-28 | NULL | 2021-01-28 | 1 | 6 |
| 7938636 | 2 | INVOICE | NULL | 1 | MD191807 | 2021-01-28 | NULL | 2021-01-28 | 1 | 4 |
| 7938631 | 2 | INVOICE | NULL | 1 | MZ320771 | 2021-01-28 | NULL | 2021-01-28 | 1 | 1 |
| 7938631 | 2 | INVOICE | NULL | 1 | 7803A112 | 2021-01-28 | NULL | 2021-01-28 | 4 | 2 |
| 7938576 | 2 | INVOICE | NULL | 1 | 8201A216 | 2021-01-29 | NULL | 2021-01-29 | 1 | 1 |
| 7938598 | 2 | INVOICE | NULL | 1 | SP046271 | 2021-01-29 | NULL | 2021-01-29 | 1 | 14 |

I've also got a script like this which finds the duplicates for me

```
WITH cte
 AS (SELECT transactionid,
            aCode,
            liNumber,
            wCode,
            RN = Row_number()
                   OVER(
                     partition BY 
                        transactionid, 
                        aCode, 
                        liNumber,
                        wCode
                     ORDER BY 
                        transactionid)
     FROM   duplicates)
SELECT * FROM   cte
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

When running that script the data shown is in a format like this..

| transactionID | aCode | liNumber | wCode | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1012751 | DISCOUNT | 9 | 1 | 2 |

I can then search for that aCode or transactionID in the duplicates table to see how many there are. So far in my duplicates table, that script returns a total of 34,791 rows. Note, items that have the same liNumber needs to be changed.

My ask is, how do I go about doing this with this large amount of data?

For example,

Transaction **7938636** might have 5 rows. All with the same **wCode** and the same **aCode** BUT the liNumber goes up in increments like 1, 2, 3, 4 ect. When a row has the same liNumber; say 1 then that is classed as a duplicate. I then need to update that duplicate row to continue the increments, from 6, 7 , 8 ect.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve].

Comment: Is this what you require?

SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18390.0

Comment: So, when a code combination has rows for the linumbers 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, you want to update 2=>3, 3=>4, 4=>5? Or only 2=>5?

Comment: So if there are 2 rows that have the same values in each of the below columns
transactionID, aCode, liNumber, wCode
00001,              XYZ1,    1,               13,
00001,              XYZ1,    1,               13,

That is a duplicate because it has the same liNumber within that criteria. If that's the case, I then want to update the duplicate row from 1 to 2.

Comment: In my example the 2 is the duplicate. But if I update 2 to 3, then I suddenly have a duplicate with number 3. So should I then update 3 to 4 and consequently 4 to 5 or should I not update 2 to 3 to start with, but 2 to 5 right away?

Comment: Don't update to start with. Only check to see if there are 2 rows that have the same liNumber of 2 then update one of them to 5. That is if there isn't a row that has a liNumber of 5.

Comment: Perhaps some sort of negation logic would work? Oddly people just ignore half the domain of any numeric column by only using positive numbers. Or just reassign line numbers for all "related" rows (based on your partition columns).

Comment: Would you consider renumbering them all: liNumber: 1,2,3,4,...? would be easier.

Comment: "In case of a duplicate number, just take the next available one" means you change the original order. This in turn makes me wonder: why have that number at all, when it has no meaning. If you want some number, you can always generate one with `ROW_NUMBER` on-the-fly.

Comment: If it's easy to update all rows again from 1,2,3,4,5 then I'm happy to do that. As a long as each row for the same aCode, wCode and transactionID has a different liNumber I'm happy.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I think "In case of a duplicate number, just take the next available one" is what I'm trying to say. If there are two rows with the same liNumber of 1, and there are a total of 10 rows that have the same aCode, wCode and transactionID, it would update that duplicate row with a liNumber of 1 to 11 as that is the next number in the sequence.

Comment: And what I am saying is: if that number has no meaning, why store it? This doesn't seem to make much sense. If you want to select such numbers, generate them ad hoc in your query.

Comment: How would I go about generating these numbers adhoc then?

Answer (score 0):

Since the liNumber is not of identical sequence like (1,2,3,4...and so on) you can go with a workaround by updating the duplicates by adding the max of the liNumber with the corresponding rownumber as below.

```
declare @tbl table(id int, wCode int, aCode varchar(50), liNumber int)

insert into @tbl
values(7938636,1,'MZ690577',1)
,(7938636,1,'MZ690577',1)
,(7938636,1,'MZ690577',2)
,(7938636,1,'MZ690577',3)
,(7938636,1,'MZ690577',8)
,(7938636,1,'MZ690577',9)
,(7938636,1,'MZ690577',9)

declare @maxvalue int = (select max(linumber) from @tbl)

;with cte as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by liNumber order by id,liNumber) partitionedrn
,@maxvalue + ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id,liNumber)maxx
from @tbl
)
update cte set liNumber = maxx
where partitionedrn > 1

select * from @tbl
```

Note: This is just a sample data and I did not consider your table to its entirety.

Comment: Hi there,

I've tried this and it's setting the liNumber for the one duplicate row of 1 to 11 and for the duplicate row of 9 it's setting it to 16. Why is this?

Comment: @NotASQLGuru Yes, because the liNumber column in your table is not in proper sequential order and hence we are calculating the max of liNumber column and adding the same with the rownumber in order to avoid duplicates (11 is not repeated for another duplicate row). Basically each and every duplicate row will receive a unique liNumber by doing like this.

Comment: Ohh OK, I understand. How could I get it to set the next incremental number? Because in the data the liNumber is in sequential order.

Comment: @NotASQLGuru Setting next incremental number will lead to duplicates again. If the max is 10 and you are going to set 11 for all the duplicate rows that would inevitably end up as a duplicate. Adding 10 to the rownumber will give us at least a credible liNumber (that is not available in the list yet) if not an immediate one.

Comment: @NotASQLGuru If you are going to be strict on liNumber's sequential order then you must recalculate the liNumber column every time using just the row_number function and that would change the liNumber for all the rows irrespective of whether it is a duplicate or not

Comment: So rather than it looking at the current sequential order and update accordingly, you're suggesting that I have it do it itself? So looks at the rows with the same details as mentioned above and sets the liNumber from 1 to X depending on how many rows there are with that criteria? If so, I think that'll work fine.

Comment: @NotASQLGuru Exactly. The liNumber will be unique at any cost if we go by this approach, but the sequential integrity cannot be achieved.

Comment: I believe that is what I require. Is this an easy change to the above script or not?